# Correct way to build an in-app notification service?

Tags: node.js, architecture, notifications, rabbitmq, message-queue

**Background**

I have a monolith Node.js + PostgreSQL app that, besides other things, needs to provide real-time in-app notifications to end users.

It is currently implemented in the following way:

- there's a db table `notifications` which has `state` (pending/sent), `userid` (id of the notification receiver), `isRead` (did a user read the notification), `type` and `body` - notification data.
- once specific resources get created or specific events occur, a various number of users should receive in-app notifications. When a notification is created, it gets persisted to the db and gets sent to the user using WebSockets. Notifications can also get created by a cron job.
- when a user receives N number of notifications of the same type, they get collapsed into one single notification. This is done via db trigger by deleting repeated notifications and inserting a new one.
- usually it works fine. But when the number of receivers exceeds several thousands, the app lags or other requests get blocked or not all notifications get sent via WebSockets.

**Examples of notifications**

- Article published
- A user is awarded with points
- A user logged in multiple times but didn't perform some action
- One user sends a friend request to another
- One user sent a message to another
- if a user receives 3+ `Article published` notifications, they get collapsed into the `N articles published` notification (`N` gets updated if new same notifications get received).

---

What I currently have doesn't seem to work very well. For example, for the `Article created` event the api endpoint that handles the creation, also handles notifications send-outs (which is maybe not a good approach - it creates ~5-6k notifications and sends them to users via websockets).

---

**Question**

How to correctly design such functionality?

Should I stay with a node.js + db approach or add a queuing service? Redis Pub/Sub? RabbitMQ?

We deploy to the k8s cluster, so adding another service is not a problem. More important question - is it really needed in my case?

I would love some general advice or resources to read on this topic.

I've read several articles on messaging/queuing/notifications system design but still don't quite get if this fits my case.

Should the queue store the notifications or should they be in the db? What's the correct way to notify thousands of users in real-time (websockets? SSE?)?

Also, the more I read about queues and message brokers, the more it feels like I'm overcomplicating things and getting more confused.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Temporal open source project](https://temporal.io/). It would allow modeling each user lifecycle as a separate program. The Temporal makes the code fully fault tolerant and preserves its full state (including local variables and blocking await calls) across process restarts.